# Unable to host angular webapp on Localhost:4200

Tags: angular, web-applications, localhost

I have been trying for around a day or two to find the fix to this problem but no respite. I have successfully compiled my webapp and eventually it shows this:

```
C:\Users**\blog-frontend>    ng server
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your 
browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-04-06T13:31:08.322Z
Hash: 48515e0683186879850d
Time: 19187ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 18 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 554 kB [initial] 
[rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 41.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.42 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

But when I go to mozilla or chrome and type localhost:4200 in url it doesn't connect and eventually shows connection timeout. I don't know what is the problem, from angular side it looks fine but from network and port side their may be some problem .

Comment: i just posted a new answer ..try out that solution

Comment: try this once `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Maybe that port is in use by something else on your PC.

Comment: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 tried this but still no lution btw what should i type in url.

Comment: @Zze I tried that by doing taskkill at that port id, and then again doing ng serve, but still no end to the problem. after i do ng serve and see the port it shows the port as listening, but i can't get what the problem is.

Comment: can it be a firewall or pc setting issue, if yes what do i need to check?

Comment: try serve it on a different port `ng serve --port 1245`

Comment: guys thanks for getting engaged in this convo, what i'm trying now is uninstalling and installing angular cli. let's see what happens

Comment: guys i tried my best but unfortunately nothing is happening, the port status is listening but the web browser don't show anything.